# How to sort a list element in a DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
        venue        innings     batting_team                  bowling_team            score       batsmen
M Chinnaswamy Stadium   1   Kolkata Knight Riders          Royal Challengers Bangalore  61     [SC Ganguly, BB McCullum, RT Ponting]
M Chinnaswamy Stadium   2   Royal Challengers Bangalore    Kolkata Knight Riders        26     [R Dravid, W Jaffer, V Kohli, JH Kallis, CL White, MV Boucher]
Feroz Shah Kotla        1   Rajasthan Royals               Delhi Daredevils             40     [T Kohli, YK Pathan, SR Watson, M Kaif]
Feroz Shah Kotla        2   Delhi Daredevils               Rajasthan Royals             55     [G Gambhir, V Sehwag, S Dhawan]
Wankhede Stadium        1   Mumbai Indians                 Royal Challengers Bangalore  47     [L Ronchi, ST Jayasuriya, DJ Thornely, RV Uthappa, PR Shah]
Wankhede Stadium        2   Royal Challengers Bangalore    Mumbai Indians               40     [S Chanderpaul, R Dravid, LRPL Taylor]
Eden Gardens            1   Deccan Chargers                Kolkata Knight Riders        39     [AC Gilchrist, Y Venugopal Rao, VVS Laxman, A Symonds]
Eden Gardens            2   Kolkata Knight Riders          Deccan Chargers              26     [WP Saha, BB McCullum, RT Ponting, SC Ganguly, DJ Hussey]
Sawai Mansingh Stadium  1   Kings XI Punjab                Rajasthan Royals             54     [K Goel, JR Hopes, KC Sangakkara]
Sawai Mansingh Stadium  2   Rajasthan Royals               Kings XI Punjab              53     [M Kaif, YK Pathan, Kamran Akmal, SR Watson, DS Lehmann]
```

As it can be seen, the `batsmen` column has lists as its elements. Now I need to sort each list. I used the code

```
df['batsmen'] = df['batsmen'].sort()
```

but I get the error as `Series object as no attribute 'sort'`. How can I achieve this so that each list in the column gets sorted in ascending order?

Comment: try values df['batsmen'] = df['batsmen'].values.sort()

Comment: Got an error as ```operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```py
df['batsmen'] = df['batsmen'].apply(sorted)
```

If you want to reverse the list, you can do

```py
df['batsmen'] = df['batsmen'].apply(lambda x: sorted(x, reversed=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, if you want to do it in-place:

```
df["batsmen"].apply(list.sort)
print(df)
```

---

EDIT: For `numpy.ndarray`:

```
df["batsmen"].apply(np.ndarray.sort)
print(df)
```

Comment: Getting error as ```descriptor 'sort' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'numpy.ndarray' object```.

Answer (score 1):

Try `df.sort_values(by="batsmen").head()`
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/07_reshape_table_layout.html

Comment: Getting error as ```operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,) ```.